# Column osm_meta in osm2po 4.6.9?

Tags: openstreetmap, metadata, osm2po

What's the utility of *osm_meta* column in osm2po (Version: 4.6.9) generated data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new osm_meta-column has been introduced to satisfy future request. In some of my test cases I populated it with Routes (Relations) e.g. of Bus-Lines or MTB-Tours.